# Does a template specialization extend or override the generic template?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    void method1(){}
 };

template<>
struct A<int>{
    void method2(){}
 };
```

Will `A<int>` have both method1 and method2? And `A<float>` will only have `method1` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Each specialization brings an entirely new data type into existence (or an entirely new template, if the specialization is only partial). From the Standard (C++11):

> (§14.5.5/2) Each class template partial specialization is a distinct template and definitions shall be provided for the members of a template partial specialization (14.5.5.3).

And:

> (§14.5.5.3/1) [...] The members of the class template partial specialization are unrelated to the members of the primary template. Class template partial specialization members that are used in a way that requires a definition shall be defined; the definitions of members of the primary template are never used as definitions for members of a class template partial specialization. [...]

The above is stated in the context of *partial* specializations, but it applies to explicit specializations (as in your case) as well, although the Standard does not say this very clearly.

Also note that you need not only declare all member functions that you want in a specialization, but you need to define them, too (here, the Standard is very clear even about explicit specializations):

> (14.7.3/5) A member of an explicitly specialized class is not implicitly instantiated from the member declaration of the class template; instead, the member of the class template specialization shall itself be explicitly defined if its definition is required. In this case, the definition of the class template explicit specialization shall be in scope
>   at the point at which the member is defined. The definition of an explicitly specialized class is unrelated to the definition of a generated specialization. That is, its members need not have the same names, types, etc. as the members of a generated specialization. [...]

So, indeed, `A<int>` will only have `method2()`, and `A<float>` will only have `method1()` as member. Furthermore, if you were to introduce `method1()` in the `A<int>` specialization as well, it needs not have the same argument types or return type as `A<float>::method1()`.

See @aschepler's answer for possible ways to avoid having to rewrite the template definition for the `int` case.

Comment: @Fellowshee Yes, you can do that. In that case, don't declare a new `template <> struct A<int> { ... };`, but simply declare (and define) the method you want to specialize: `A<int>::method1() { ... };` outside the class template definition.

Comment: Interesting, an out-of-class declaration and definition of a function that is not mentioned inside the class at all is considered legal?

Comment: @Fellowshee Oh sorry, I thought you needed a specialization of `method1` for the `int` case. If you really need to add an entirely new `method2` for the `int` case only, then indeed, you'll need to rewrite the entire template for `int`. Depending on the situation, it may be better then to add `method2` to the primary template definition but leave it undefined (or have it throw an exception, or put in a `static_asssert(false,"not implemented");` (the latter works only in C++11)). That way you could specialize `method2` for the `int` case without having to rewrite the entire template.

Comment: I'm reading this Herb Sutter article which suggests that partial template specialization for a class (as opposed to the full specializations we have been discussing) might solve my issue without having to rewrite the  entire template for an added function in a special case: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @Fellowshee Not sure I understand... the article is mostly about function templates (as opposed to class templates). Also, to be clear about the term _partial specialization_: It means that only _some_ of the template parameters are instantiated. It does not mean that only some parts of the class definition are specialized.

Comment: I should perhaps make another question out of this, but at the beginning of the article he shows the example of making a partial class template specialization as different than the full class specializations we have been discussing. He then goes on to talk about function templates more specifically.

Comment: @Fellowshee Yes, a separate question with the specifics of your situation (e.g. how is `method2` used etc.) may be useful. In any case, be sure not to misunderstand what _partial specialization_ means. In the example at the beginning of the article, the specialization is partial, because it is for pointer types `T*`, i.e. the types it can be applied to must be pointers, but they are otherwise free to be whatever they want. In this sense, the specialization is partial, but the class definition itself must still be provided in full.

Answer (score 19):

@jogojapan's answer explains what the language does.  Here's a couple workarounds if you do want to add new members for a specific specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct A_Base {
    void method1() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct A : public A_Base<T> {};

template<>
struct A<int>
  : public A_Base<int>
{
    void method2() {}
};
```

Now `A<int>` has members `method1` and `method2`, but `A<float>` has no `method2`.

OR (if you can modify the primary template)...

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    void method1() {}

    template<int N=0>
    auto method2() ->
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value && N==N>::type
    {}
};
```

The `template<int N>` and `N==N` parts make sure `std::enable_if` has a dependent value and therefore doesn't complain until somebody actually tries to use `A<T>::method2` with an incorrect `T` parameter.

---

And since this question and answer seem to still be getting attention, a much later edit to add that in C++20, you can simply do:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    void method1() {}

    void method2() requires std::is_same_v<T, int> {}
};
```

Comment: @aschepler - Would the first technique (non C++11 technique) work if `A_Base` was *not* a template? That is, can you have an `A<int>::A_Base::method2`? I'm getting an error out of MSVC and I have never seen the error before ([C2936](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctfzt48x.aspx)). I'm not sure if its not possible, not possible with C++03, or if its a MSVC limitation.

Comment: @jww Yes, it should work. I'm not sure why you might get that error. The page you linked suggests checking for mismatched braces. If you still don't see a dumb mistake, you may want to write and test a [mcve] and post a new question about it.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler. After studying it a bit more, the problem I am facing is a little different... I want override (specialize?) a class member in a non-template base. That is, I need to provide a specialized body for `A<int>::A_Base::method1`. Let me see if I can find a discussion of it.

Comment: Shouldn't A_base declare a virtual destructor?

Comment: @fiorentinoing Probably not necessary, as the purpose of `A_base` is not to act as a useful interface, just to help declare the wanted functions. So it's not really expected anyone would be using an `A_base*` or `std::unique_ptr<A_base>` or so on.

Comment: @aschepler the postfix "_base" is then just misleading to me. Thanks to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The specialisation replaces the generic template. So `A<int>` will only have `method2()` and, of course, `A<double>` will only have `method1()`.

Comment: I suppose then that the compiler will treat them as entirely separate classes with no relationship between them, as if they had entirely different names (which in the created source they probably do?)

Comment: Every type generated from a template is an entirely separate class with no relation at all with other types generated from the same template. This makes no difference. `A<int>`, `A<double>` and `A<char>` would be three unrelated classes.