# Class partial specialization inheriting methods

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods

```
template <unsigned N>
class A {
    void common_function();
};

template <>
class A<1> {
    void new_functionality();
};
```

I want class `A<1>` to inherit `common_function()` from `A` class.

This would be useful if you need to add some functionality to classes partial specialization, but don't want to duplicate common methods.

Comment: You can inherit stuff from a base class.

Comment: @user253751 I can't inherit A<1> from A, because A is a template class. On the other hand, I am also not able to inherit both A<1> and A from a base class, because in common functions I would like to use template parameter N.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765179

Comment: @RomanovSaveliy Correct! So you will need to create a base class. And because you want to use template parameter N, your base class must be a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you say partial specialization, this is actually an explicit specialization. Not that it matters either way as both explicit and partial specializations are separate types from the base template.

The way to achieve  what you want is to introduce another type (likely not a template at all) to deal with the shared functionality, and derive both your base template and the specializations from that type.

```
struct shared
{
  void common_function() { ... } 
};

template<unsigned N>
class a : public shared
{ void foo() { std::cout << "a<N>::foo" << std::endl; }
};

template<>
class a<1> : public shared
{
  void foo() { .std::cout << "a<1>::foo" << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: If common_function() used template parameter N, your solution won't work. While I want common_function() in A<1> to work as if it was called from class A with N = 1.